A paradox about calculating ground state energy in QFT
I found two ways to calculate the ground state energy in a QFT. They seem right both but give different result, I don't know what I did wrong.
Method 1: The ground state energy is vacumm bubbles
According to Peskin Eq.(4.56), we have:
$$
E_{g}^{(1)} = \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty(1-i \epsilon)} \ln \langle 0| T \exp[-i \int_{-\tau}^\tau d t H_I(t)] |0\rangle/(-i 2 \tau)
$$
Method 2: We could consider $\langle{\Omega}|H|{\Omega}\rangle$ directly
By Gell-Mann & Low theorem, we have:
$$
E_{g}^{(2)} = \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty(1-i \epsilon)} \frac{\langle 0| T\left\{H_I(0) e^{\left.-i \int_{-\tau}^\tau d t H_I(t)\right.} \right\}|0\rangle}{\langle 0| T \exp \left[-i \int_{-\tau}^\tau d t H_I(t)|0\rangle\right.}
$$
Comment:
(1) By explicit calculations of some 0+1d examples (QM examples, so I can check with the right result), I found $E^{(1)}_{g}$ does give the correct result, while $E^{(2)}=\lambda \frac{\partial E^{(1)}}{\lambda}$ if I let $H_{I}\rightarrow \lambda H_{I}$ and do expansion with respect to $\lambda$.
(2) It can be shown in general that we do have $E^{(2)}=\lambda \frac{\partial E^{(1)}}{\lambda}$:
Let $H_{I}\rightarrow \lambda H_{I}$,
$$
\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}(2\tau E_{g}^{(1)}) = \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty(1-i \epsilon)} \frac{\langle 0| T\left\{\int_{-\tau}^{\tau}dt' \lambda H_I(t') e^{\left.-i \int_{-\tau}^\tau d t \lambda H_I(t)\right.} \right\}|0\rangle}{\langle 0| T \exp \left[-i \int_{-\tau}^\tau d t \lambda H_I(t)|0\rangle\right.} = 2\tau E^{(2)}_{g}
$$
(3)However, by definition, it seems that the "Method 2" should be correct. And if we admit $\lim_{\tau}$ commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$, by $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}(2\tau E_{g}^{(1)})=2E_{g}^{(1)}=2E_{g}^{(2)}$ we can show that $E^{(2)}_{g}=E^{(1)}_{g}$. What did I do wrong about the "Method 2"?

I do not quite understand why you multiply a $2\tau$ with $E_g^{(1)}$, obviously this is wrong. And in the second step, the integral over $t'$ contains a time dependent operator $H_I$ and you should pay attention to the time ordering, so maybe it is illegal to extract a $2\tau$ factor. These are my naive guess, but there is no doubt that if you calculate by Gell-Mann&Low thm you can have the right answer.

@say In fact, it is $E_{g}^{(1)}$ gives the right answer in any examples. And $E_{g}^{(2)}$ is always $\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}E^{(1)}_{g}$.

I understand what I did wrong: The second approach is obviously right, but in the formula above $\langle H_{0}\rangle$ which is in fact none-zero is missing.

$\lambda \frac{\partial E_{g}^{1}}{\partial \lambda}=\frac{\partial E_{g}^{1}}{\partial \ln (\lambda)}$
